# Server not showing updated web pages all the time

Tags: domain-name-system, cache, web

Our website has been update a while ago but when it is viewed from the domain location we still see the older web pages.  There are over 10 workstation at this site and WiFi. Some of the computers will show the updated web pages sometime.If I view the web page from another location I see all the updated web pages. I've tried clearing the DNS server cache and flushing the DNS and no change. Does anyone have a solution for this.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried clearing the DNS server cache and flushing the DNS and no change.

Why? did you move IP addresses?

ALL dns is doing is translating a domain name into an IP. What you say is like "the car does not work, I alrady changed the number plates and it still does not work".

> Does anyone have a solution for this.

Is there a transparent proxy involved? Did you program it properly regarding IMF settings ("If MOdified Since") and have proper NoCache attributes in the HTML?

Two reasons. EITHER the BROWSER caches due to some settings, or a proxy on the way caches. The second problem MAY be unsolvable (transparent stupid proxy = requries admin to change it, which may or may not be an option) but can be worked around.